# Distance dropdown disappearing

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

The distance dropdown in the Location box will not let me select a value.

Steps to reproduce:

- Search for anything
- Pull up the Location --> Distance menu
- Hover over any value in the list

The entire dropdown disappears.  If I click the Distance menu, then use my keyboard to navigate and select one of the options, the option works.

Version information: Firefox 42.0

Comment: Confirmed. Looks like is Firefox specific. I'll put it on the bug board.

Comment: @juice I.E. as well, with somewhat different symptoms. See my post which was closed as a dup (even though it's got much more detail).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We actually fixed this [many moons ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253204/stack-overflow-careers-cant-select-mileage/253269#253269) but didn't tackle the case where the search term changed. I've just fixed it and pushed to prod.

Thanks for the report! :)